# Quickest way to check multiple bools and changing image depending on that bool

Tags: swift, loops

I have multiple achievements that the user can achieve during the game. When the user goes to the achievement VC, he should see an image when the achievement is accomplished.

I am now using this code in the viewDidLoad function:

```
if unlockedAchievement1 == true
        {
            achievement1Text.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            achievement1Image.image = UIImage(named: "achievement1Unlocked")
        }
        if unlockedAchievement2 == true
        {
            achievement2Text.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            achievement2Image.image = UIImage(named: "achievement2Unlocked")
        }
```

This would work, but it takes a lot of time to copy paste this overtime. How can I shorten this? Should I make a class? I read about for in loops, but I did not quite understood that. Any help is welcome!

Comment: You might want to use a guard statement if the context is right. Might help to clarify the code and avoid unnecessary pyramids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I have seen this before. But anyway...

```
//use array of bools. First declare as empty array.
//Use Core data to achieve saving the Booleans if you need to. 
let achievements:[Bool] = [] 
let achievementsImage:[UIImage] = []
let achievementsText:[UITextView] = []

func viewDidLoad() {
    //Say you have 5 achievements.
    for index in 0 ..< 5 {
        achievements.append(false)
        achievementsImage.append(UIImage(named: "achievementLocked"))
        achievementText.append(UITextView())
        //Then you can edit it, such as.
        achievementText[index].frame = CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        achievementText[index].text = "AwesomeSauce"
        self.view.addSubview(achievementText[index])
        achievementText[index].textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}

//Call this function and it will run through your achievements and determine what needs to be changed
func someFunction() {
    for index in 0 ..< achievements.count {
        if(achievements[index]) {
            achievements[index] = true
            achievementsImage[index] = UIImage(named: String(format: "achievement%iUnlocked", index))
            achievementsText[index].textColor = UIColor.greenColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I firstly get an error: Cannot assign through subscript: achievements is a let constant. I changed it to a var. I declared it first as an empty array as you said, and than tried to load it, but it crashes because the array was out of index. I added 5 times false to the achievements array, tried it again and than it crashed because " unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The breakpoint is set to "  achievementsImage[index] = UIImage(named: "achievementLocked")!". How can I get rid of this errors?

Comment: Haha my bad. Stupid mistakes on my part. Ima edit it

Comment: Check it now, should be error free. But haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Only 1 thing remains, what is the quickest way to set all the achievement images? Now I am doing this:         achievement1Image.image = achievementsImage[0]
        achievement2Image.image = achievementsImage[1] Is there a way to shorten this also? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean. Could you elaborate or show code?

Comment: I have created outlets for all of my image views. They are listed like achievement1Image, achievement2Image, ect. The images that are in the array, must be set to the right image view. I can do it by doing  achievement1Image.image = achievementsImage[0] achievement2Image.image = achievementsImage[1] , but I was wondering if i could speed up this process else I have 47 lines of code unnecessary right?

Comment: You should look up how to do an array of outlets. So then you. So then the array could be achievementImages then say achievementImages[index].image = achievementImage[index]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making your `unlockedAchievement1`, `unlockedAchievement2`, etc. objects tuples, with the first value being the original Bool, and the second value being the image name. You'd use this code:

```
// First create your data array
var achievements = [(Bool, String)]()
// Then you can make your achievements.
// Initially, they're all unearned, so the Bool is false.
let achievement1 = (false, "achievement1UnlockedImageName")
achievements.append(achievement1)
let achievement2 = (false, "achievement2UnlockedImageName")
achievements.append(achievement2)

// Now that you have your finished data array, you can use a simple for-loop to iterate.
// Create a new array to hold the images you'll want to show.
var imagesToShow = [String]()
for achievement in achievements {
    if achievement.0 == true {
        imagesToShow.append(achievement.1)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I read it correctly I am creating an array with just the images to be shown, right? But how could this automatically change the image?

Comment: Let's say you have 10 achievements. `imagesToShow.count` would be the number of images that are unlocked, and `10 - imagesToShow.count` would be the number of images that are the default locked image.